# Calculate distances with spatial join - geopandas

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, geopandas

import requests, io, json
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import pandas as pd

I have two GeoPandas DataFrames.

`gpd1` with `POLYGON` geometry
`gpd2` with `POINT` geometry

Example data:

```
res = requests.get(
    "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/69dc11c7386943b4ad8893c45648b1e1_0.geojson"
)
gpd1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(res.json()["features"], crs="CRS84").pipe(
    lambda d: d.rename(columns={c: c.lower() for c in d.columns})
).rename(columns={"lad20cd": "areaCode","lad20nm":"areaName"})


# get some public addressess - hospitals.  data that can be scattered
dfhos = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("http://media.nhschoices.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text),
    sep="¬",engine="python",)


# create a geo dataframe of hospitals
gpd2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data=dfhos,
        geometry=dfhos.apply(lambda r: shapely.geometry.Point(r["Longitude"],r["Latitude"]), axis=1), crs="EPSG:4326"
    )
```

I spatial join them:

```
gpd1.sjoin(gpd2, how='left')
```

I'd like to also calculate the distances for each row joined. How do I calculate the distance and include `distance` as a column? Note, that each `POINT` in `gpd2` is within the `POLYGON`.

Comment: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html

Comment: omg - did you check this sample code still runs?  `{'errors': {'title': 'Resource Not Found',
  'status': 404,
  'message': 'The requested resource was not found.'},
 'meta': {}}`

Comment: @RobRaymond no, I applied it directly on my own code. It worked fine.

Comment: your own code - I recognise it,  I provided in an answer many months ago...  ok as always with your questions start by fixing gen-z type issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- as is common with your questions, either ambiguous or your sample code does not begin to work
- have fixed sample code to use UK counties and UK towns / cities
- result of an `sjoin()` is a column **right_index**  This can be used to construct a series of the points
- then it's a simple case of use **geopandas** `distance()` to get the distance

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import requests, io


# some polygons
gpd1 = gpd.read_file(
    requests.get("https://www.geoboundaries.org/api/current/gbOpen/GBR/ADM2").json()[
        "simplifiedGeometryGeoJSON"
    ]
)

# some points
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get("https://simplemaps.com/static/data/country-cities/gb/gb.csv").text
    )
)


gpd2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["lng"], df["lat"]), crs="epsg:4326"
)


gpd_sj = gpd1.sjoin(gpd2, how="inner").reset_index()
gpd_sj["distance"] = gpd_sj.distance(gpd2.loc[gpd_sj["index_right"]])
gpd_sj.loc[:, ["index", "shapeName", "index_right", "city", "distance"]]
```

|  | index | shapeName | index_right | city | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Hartlepool | 1606 | Seaton Carew | 3.29536 |
| 1 | 0 | Hartlepool | 96 | Hartlepool | 2.22489 |
| 2 | 1 | Middlesbrough | 2466 | Stainton | 1.41667 |
| 3 | 1 | Middlesbrough | 1849 | Nunthorpe | 0.766652 |
| 4 | 1 | Middlesbrough | 1129 | Marton | 0.581443 |
| 5 | 1 | Middlesbrough | 36 | Middlesbrough | 1.8294 |
| 6 | 2 | Redcar and Cleveland | 1628 | Ormesby | 3.30945 |
| 7 | 2 | Redcar and Cleveland | 635 | Guisborough | 2.11976 |
| 8 | 2 | Redcar and Cleveland | 1330 | Loftus | 3.68467 |
| 9 | 2 | Redcar and Cleveland | 1167 | Skelton | 3.60919 |

Comment: What unit of measurement is `distance` in?